# Has anyone got a LinkedIn follow button to work?

Tags: linkedin-api

Has anyone got a LinkedIn follow button to work? Like others, i just get a blank page when clicking it. And i can´t find any solutions in the existing threads here at Stack Overflow. 
I have tried the following code snippet. it shows the button and a counter for the number of followers, but does not work when you click it.

```
<script src="https://platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript"> 
lang: en_US</script>
<script type="IN/FollowCompany" data-id="1337" data-counter="top"></script>
```

Is there another way to implement this button?

Comment: did you ever get this resolved?  I'm trying to add a linkedin follow button and came across the same code you reference above.  I can't even get it to show the button and number of followers.

Comment: @SteveElmer No, sorry. I couldn´t get it to work so we ended up with just a regular link to the LinkedIn page.